How to identify unsafe trees for climbing stand?
I am new to hunting (in my 40s) and have been out half a dozen times or so this year.  I should note that after trying for years to find a mentor that I could learn from, I gave up and started figuring it out on my own.  The first few times I went out, I kept to daylight hours so I could get familiar with my gear and process.  The last time I went out, I chose to go early (about 4am) and realized that I didn't really know how to reliably tell if a tree was unsafe under the circumstances because:

It was very dark
The leaves had fallen from the branches, so even once it was light, it was hard to tell which trees had dead branches.

How do you all handle this?  Do you only hunt in areas you scouted earlier in the year (and where you identify specific trees to hang in)?
edit-
Should have mentioned that my concern is finding a safe tree to climb in my climbing stand

Are you trying to climb the trees or are you just afraid that some branch will fall on your head?

@PMF Sorry for the ambiguity - edited to explain that I am looking for safe trees to climb with a climbing stand.

I am not a hunter nor a tree climber, but I have a lot of trees on my property, and I keep an eye on them (to, e.g., prevent them from falling on the house or overshading the understory.)  There are two reasons why my answer to the question in your next to last sentence is "Yes!".
The first, and less important, reason is that you want a good line of sight in several directions for a successful hunt, and you can figure this out only in daylight, and ideally with knowledge of the surrounding area.  So you need to scout not only the tree, but the area, to find not just an adequate tree, but one of the better trees for your purpose.
The second reason is that even when the leaves are out, a branch can be cracked, or partly rotten or otherwise fragile, and you cannot rule this out in darkness (and not always in the light).  I have been surprised by what seemed like a good branch falling unexpectedly.

I am a hunter.  You identify the tree in the daylight not only for safety but also if the location is ideal for hunting.
Do you have good views of travel corridors and the deer trails in the area?  Are there better trees that will provide some cover and break up your profile in the tree (you mention having a climber so this can be tricky).  Depending on the hunting (bow or firearm), are there any branches that you need to be concerned about in your shooting lanes?
If you haven't done much scouting, I wouldn't hunt from the tree the first morning.  I would sit on the ground or go out later in the morning when I can see and can set up my stand in the daylight.  Hunting the stand in the evening and then the next morning would be able to get up the tree in the dark knowing the area and that the tree was safe.
Also if you are on public land, knowing if there are other stands in the area is something that you don't want to learn at 4am.
